# Don't copy rows of existing multiple columns in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks W1 and W2 that will copy all visible rows of W1 to W2. I need a macro that will not copy the visible rows if values of **Column 3 and Column 4 in W1 already exist in Column 5 and Column 8 of W2**. this is what I have so far.

**Worksheet W1 sheet1:**

[image]

**Worksheet W2 sheet1:**
[image]

**Expected result when Button is clicked:**
[image]

Only the 2 highlighted rows is copied to W2 because **Column 3 and Column 4 Row 5 in W1 already exist in Column 5 and Column 8 Row 1935 in W2** even if the dates are different.

**Code: (Only copy all visible rows in W1 to W2)**

```
Private Sub Send_Click()

 Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
 Dim wsDest As Worksheet

 Dim W2 as String

 W2 = "D:\Worksheet2.xlsm"


'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
Set wsCopy = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsDest = Workbooks.Open(W2).Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
lDestLastRow = wsDest.Range("table1").Columns(1).Find(What:="", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row


wsCopy.Range("A5:A5000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
wsDest.Cells(lDestLastRow, 1).PasteSpecial

wsCopy.Range("C5:C5000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
wsDest.Cells(lDestLastRow, 5).PasteSpecial

wsCopy.Range("D5:D5000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
wsDest.Cells(lDestLastRow, 8).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Comment: Two approaches you might consider. 1. Step through the source range row by row, test to see if the row already exists in the target range, and copy if not. 2. Copy all the visible rows in the source range to the target range and then remove duplicates.

Comment: Here's some code that will be useful. `Dim rngCopy As Range: Dim arrCopy As Variant: With wsCopy: Set rngCopy = .Range(.Cells(5, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)): arrCopy = rngCopy.Value: End With` Now you can either paste the visible cells from *rngCopy* to a temporary sheet or area that you designate for that purpose and process all rows as @Nicolas Hunter has described or you can use *arrCopy* to sort both visible and eligible in one loop and copy only those you approve.

Comment: How many rows does W1 have that need to copy? Build arrays of what is in W2 to start with, then iterate through each row in W1, checking if they exist in the arrays, if not, copy.